# export field from phpmyadmin - texy

Tags: text, phpmyadmin, xampp, export

> ===Database 201507== Dumping data for table car123|6|bmw|cash

how to remove text on line before data

> ===Database 201507
>
> == Dumping data for table car123

i want the result :

> car123|6|bmw|cash

phpmyadmin from bundling latest xampp installer,
os: win 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with upgrade mysql version and put delimited